# How do you run Espresso Test Suite Test Classes Synchronously in the same activity?

Tags: java, android, junit4, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I want to run a set of tests synchronously. Ideally, I want these sets of tests to be modularized into separate classes since combining them into 1 class will be too big of a file. For example, I have the following test suite file:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        LoginTest.class,
        AddItemsTest.class,
        ItemTest.class,
        ArchiveTest.class,
        LogoutTest.class
})
public class FullTest{}
```

These test cases run in order, however I'm confused on continuing to use the same context and activity between these test cases. I am getting errors when running the tests of it not finding an activity...

```
E/TestRunner: failed: runAddItems(com.XXX.XXX.functional.TestSuite.AddItemsTest)
    ----- begin exception -----
E/TestRunner: java.lang.RuntimeException: No activities found. Did you forget to launch the activity by calling getActivity() or startActivitySync or similar?
        at androidx.test.espresso.base.RootViewPicker.waitForAtLeastOneActivityToBeResumed(RootViewPicker.java:176)
        at androidx.test.espresso.base.RootViewPicker.get(RootViewPicker.java:88)
        at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule.provideRootView(ViewInteractionModule.java:77)
        at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.provideRootView(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:37)
        at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.get(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:27)
        at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.get(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:10)
        at androidx.test.espresso.base.ViewFinderImpl.getView(ViewFinderImpl.java:63)
        at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:280)
        at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:272)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6949)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
    ----- end exception -----
```

Is there anything specific i have to do to continue in the workflow where I left off in the last test case?

Answer (score 0):

I didnt think it was a valid solution, but I figured it out. I just create a separate Test class, and create an instance of it in my test.. this worked.